# How exactly does MySQL compare values

Tags: mysql, comparison

In a table

```
id     | name
----------------
1      | a
170    | abcde
```

with a query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE name = abc
```

I want to know what MySQL does as a first step:

1 - compares the length of the values?

OR

2 - compares the first character and then the next one and so on?

OR

3 - compares the full values regardless of their (non-) similarity?

Are strings and integers compared differently?

Thanks

Comment: This is utter irrelevant to the performance of the query.  If you want to improve performance, create an index on the column.

Comment: So you say, point number 3 is the right answer?